# Sound does not work / “No Audio Output Device Is Installed” after 21h1 (May 2021) windows update

Tags: audio, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v21h1

After installing the lastest windows update, my sound does not work. It shows a red X in the taskbar and on hover it says "No Audio Output Device is installed.":

[image: no audio output device is installed]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following steps:

1. Open a powershell window as an administrator
2. Paste the following script into the powershell window

```
REG EXPORT "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations" WinStations_backup.reg
$WinStationsPath="HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations"
$value = Get-ItemProperty -Path $WinStationsPath -Name DefaultSecurity
Set-ItemProperty -Path $WinStationsPath -Name ConsoleSecurity -Value $value.DefaultSecurity
```

3. Reboot you computer
4. Your sound should be working now

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/lost-all-audio-after-may-2021-windows-10-update/e0e6ec45-f3a8-497f-9d4d-316d9c5f13ca?page=4